# HTTP Auth coordinated by web application rather than server

Tags: python, django, http, authentication, http-authentication

I'm working with Django on Linux and I have an application that integrates with Active Directory.  I'm seeking opinions and advice about whether or not it would be feasible or reasonable to access the HTTP headers from within the application to coordinate HTTP authentication.

The end goal would be to perform NTLM authentication without a password, which I accept may be quite a bit of work and research.

Note, this is a more general version of my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120956/django-to-do-its-own-ntlm-authentication-http-headers-all), which received no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just return a `HttpResponse` with a 401 status code, and tell your web server-Django connector to let the auth headers through.